# Intersection in single pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

```
       0
0  [g,k]
1  [e,g]
2  [e]
3  [k,e]
4  [s]
5  [g]
```

I am trying to get the value which appears once in the data column, in this example the solution should be 's'.

But I can only find methods to solve this problem while having two series or two dataframe columns.
I can't do it in one column, because if the value is part of a combination unique won't work as far as I know.

Comment: are you looking for `df['0'].explode().value_counts().loc[lambda x: x==1]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need test if one value only is possible use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and then filter `index` by `1` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df[0].explode().value_counts()
L = s.index[s == 1].tolist()
print (L)
['s']
```

Or use pure python solution with `Counter` and flatten nested lists in `Series` in list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

L = [k for k, v in Counter([y for x in df[0] for y in x]).items() if v == 1]
print (L)
['s']
```